# invalidate chromecast remote display

Tags: android, google-cast, invalidation

I currently am trying to make a drawing on the chromecast through the remote display. I can cast my custom view to the chromecast. However when I start drawing on the second screen nothing appears on the firstscreen (chromecast). Now I think this was because I made two instances of my custom view. So my next plan was to include my secondscreen in hope that it would automaticly refresh when I started drawing, this did not happen. How can I force the remote display to invalidate (without having acces to the class) ?

firstscreen layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/myframelayout">

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/castscreen">

        <include layout="@layout/second_screen_layout"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is up to your apps logic to synchronize the mobile and remote display views. The Remote Display API does not have any mechanism to synchronize views. If your are using OpenGL, you can share the renderer instance between the mobile and remote display views.

Comment: Thanks for the information :). I'm going to try that right away!

Comment: So i first created the drawing app on a canvas which worked well on my phone. However i have never worked with OpenGL. I have been googeling alot, but i can't find anything that works. Do you perhaps know any kind of tutorial for free drawing in OpenGL?